# using HAVING to filter results based on a reference row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+---------+--------------+----------+
| item_id | location_id  |  price   |
+---------+--------------+----------+
|       1 |            1 |      100 |
|       1 |            1 |      250 |
|       1 |            2 |       50 |
|       2 |            1 |      250 |
|       2 |            1 |     1000 |
|       3 |            1 |     1000 |
|       3 |            2 |      100 |
+---------+--------------+----------+
```

I can reduce this down to the minimum values using this query

```
SELECT 
    item_id, location_id, MIN(price) AS Price
from
    table
GROUP BY item_id , location_id
```

This gets me

```
+---------+--------------+----------+
| item_id | location_id  |  price   |
+---------+--------------+----------+
|       1 |            1 |      100 |
|       1 |            2 |       50 |
|       2 |            1 |      250 |
|       3 |            1 |     1000 |
|       3 |            2 |      100 |
+---------+--------------+----------+
```

I want to reduce this further. I am using the rows with a **location_id** of 1 as a reference row. For each row that has an item_id matching the reference row's item_id but a different location id. I want to compare that row's price with the reference row's price. If the price is lower than the reference row's price, I want to filter that row out.

My final result should include the reference row for each item id and any rows that met the criteria of the price being lower than the reference row price.

I have a hunch that I can use the **HAVING** clause to do this but I am having trouble compiling the statement. How should I construct the HAVING statement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show your expected result with your example above?

Answer (score 1):

Nah, having can't help you like this, having is for things like you need filter min() result for something

e.g:

```
select id,min(price) from table where date = '2016-3-18' group by id having min(price) = 50
```

it will show you the records that min(price)=50

let's back to your case, there are lots of way to do that,

**1. left join**

```
select a.item_id,a.location_id,a.price
from table a 
left join table b
on a.location_id = b.location_id and a.price > b.price
where b.price is null
```

**2. exists**

```
select a.item_id,a.location_id,a.price
from table a
where exists(
select 1 from
(select location_id,min(price)as price from table group by location_id)b
where a.location_id = b.location_id and a.price = b.price
 )
```

normally i ll recommand you use exists